# Placing an "anchor" in GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen, scrolling

Usually, especially when debugging code, I have the code spit out a ton of data and since I'm using GNU Screen, I scroll back through the output to see what I need. But it's not always easy to find the start location of the data I want to see.

Is it possible to drop an "anchor" of sorts before I run the command so I can then tell screen "Hey, take me back to the line where I dropped that anchor" so I don't have to scroll through and find it myself?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that GNU Screen can insert any invisible marks into the scroll-back buffer but you can certainly put there visible marks either from a shell or from the code being debugged. Just chose a string which is unlikely to show in the scroll-back and print it there:

```
echo '### anchor1 ###'
```

Then when you need to go back to the "anchor", switch to the scroll-back mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,  <kbd>[</kbd> and search backward: <kbd>?</kbd>.